# Nuking Answers - Semaphore

Tags: support, editing

Someone seems to be wiping out accepted answers to questions.  How can this be stopped?

Comment: By "wiping out", you're talking about someone maliciously editing the accepted answer's content?

Comment: @JarrodDixon "Maliciously" I can't speak for, but the user in question (or someone using his account) definitely went in and replaced all content in several of his accepted answers with a numeric string. Since the behavior only lasted for 20 minutes or so (near as I can tell), I just reverted what I saw. But this users' account activity may well bear watching for a while.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange; I'll ask our community team check it out.

Comment: Related, is I do not follow this forums practice of "deleting answers" that attempt to answer the question. I have not seen this in other SE areas. It has now happened to me twice with no explanation (I don't know by who) and was a reasonable answer/theory based on the limited information in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Flag the ones you see, and they can be rolled back to the last good revision. I've gotten all the ones I noticed.

Comment: I left you a comment in chat to this effect as well, but don't forget that you can temporarily suspend a user to get them to stop this sort of behaviour. There's a stock "self-destruction of own content" message template you can use.